# read files with empty entries for certain columns

Tags: python

Right now I have a file in this format:

[image]

I need to compare the values from column 5 and 6 to my input, so I'm trying to iterate over the whole file using (assuming file f has been instantiated):

```
for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        columns = line.split()
        if (list[0] == columns[4]):
            if (list[1] == columns[5]):
                self.mass = float(columns[13]) + float(columns[14])
```

However, as sometimes the first column has empty entries, my 'columns' index get shifted over by 1, and I'd be comparing entries from column 6 and 7 instead. Is there a way to get around this?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Why do people post images of text? is that really easier than copy/pasting the text?

Comment: Point is that your format doesn't tell us in which way the entries are aligned, so it's actually pretty complicated to answer your question based on a screenshot.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! I'm new to this so don't really know which is the better way, plus when I pasted it it doesn't seem to be aligned right so...

Comment: It also makes it impossible for us to snag the text and _test_ something, so you might get vague suggestions, at best.  I'd suggest trying `pyparsing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your file is actually a tab separated file, in which case you can change this line

```
line = line.strip()
columns = line.split()
```

to this

```
columns = line.split("\t")
```

to preserve the number of elements in that array post split

If this isn't the case, then you may have to do a check on what the length of the array of your line you're currently on is in order to know which indexes to compare.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be separated by tab, and the length of 'columns' range from 15-17 (there are other entries than the first column that can be empty), and I'm not sure how to get to the right column :(

Comment: Since that's the case, someone else might know of a better way but you might just have to check for the number of columns per row and have different logic to compare which columns you want based on how large the length of the array is. This is a pretty hacky way of doing it though and make it tough to deal with if different numbers of columns appear.  You should try and find out exactly how those columns are separated though, and that should be your delimiter.